# How to set LiveCard.PublishMode in publish in XE12?

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I am trying to update my modified stopwatch example for XE12 since it now doesnt work. I'm having a hard time figuring out how to use the new publish. Could somebody please give an example of what the code looks like to set REVEAL mode or SILENT mode?

I have tried `mLiveCard.publish(REVEAL);` as well as setting LiveCard.PublishMode to REVEAL, but then I don't understand how to actually make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's how the GDK timer sample changed to support the changes in XE12](https://github.com/googleglass/gdk-timer-sample/commit/ae1dbfd5f4db5a79e283820aab95846122842085#diff-c441028ebc6c6127c94241c9e518338c).  With respect to publishing LiveCards...

- Modifications to XE12 caused the following lines to be deleted:

  ```
  mLiveCard.setNonSilent(true)

  mLiveCard.publish()
  ```
- And these added:

  ```
  import com.google.android.glass.timeline.LiveCard.PublishMode;

  mLiveCard.publish(PublishMode.REVEAL);
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, I actually was able to find the answer myself. You are supposed to use `PublishMode.REVEAL` or `PublishMode.SILENT` so the code would look like this: `mLiveCard.publish(PublishMode.REVEAL);`

Sorry for the stupid question.